# How to stop Firefox debugger server without restarting Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, vscode-tasks

I have a VSCode config that will start the Firefox debugger server with `-start-debugger-server`, so that I can run an npm script and launch a website in my existing firefox windows without having to run a special firefox window with the debug server enabled.

Is there a way to turn the debugger server off short of re-starting Firefox? Something like a `-stop-debugger-server` CLI argument would be nice but there doesn't appear to be such a flag.

I've tried `-stop-debugger-server`, tried looking in the [firefox CLI wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions), tried a web search. Stopped short of trying to re-start Firefox from the command line